# trouble with parsing in JSON

Tags: node.js, json

i am trying to run this code but it keeps giving me a ReferenceError: json is not defined. Am I putting the JSON parse in the wrong position or something? This is basically a scraper, so it returns a lot of information and that is why it needs to be parsed

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://siteToParse.com/api/v1/timelines/public',
    json: true,
};
    obj = JSON.parse(json);

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('headers', res.headers);
    console.log('status code', res.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
});
```

**EDIT**: I changed it to obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body)) and it didn't throw any errors at all. But it's still returned a lot of information, and I'm not sure what to do with it?

Comment: You just need to call `JSON.parse(body)` to turn the string into something usable (object, array, etc.). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: i made some changes but it is throwing a reference error now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should rewrite it as this:

```
const request = require('request');

const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://siteToParse.com/api/v1/timelines/public',
    json: true,
};


request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    if (err) {
        console.dir(err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('headers', res.headers);
    console.log('status code', res.statusCode);
    console.log(body);
    obj = JSON.parse(body); //---------------------> call to parse should come here
    console.log(obj);
});
```

Comment: thank you, that worked although it gave me an error after it scraped the info. Here was the error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1`

Comment: First make sure body is a valid json string.

Comment: I changed it to `obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body))` and it didn't throw any errors at all. But it's still returned a lot of information, and I'm not sure what to do with it?

Comment: I don't know what this API is for, but perhaps just keep the information you need? something like `obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(body.somInfo))`